# ExpressionEngine 3 - Template Routing issue

Tags: regex, uri, expressionengine

I have a template route like the following:

```
`/{static_country:regex[(zh|cn|usa)]}/{alpha_dash}`
```

which matches a URI like `website.com/usa/about-us` fine and points to my template I've called `static` - this works fine.

However, when I navigate to something like `website.com/usa/sdfsdfsdfsd` which is a **fake** route and isn't a route matching an entry in my channel, it still points to the first entry in the `static` channel instead of throwing a `404`.

I know I can limit this using regex like:

```
`/{static_country:regex[(zh|cn|usa)]}/{static_page:regex[(about-us)]}`
```

But that isn't very dynamic if the client adds their own pages as we'd have to update the regex each time.

Is there a way around this at all?

Comment: By looking at the template route, I do not see why `website.com/usa/sdfsdfsdfsd` should not match. `usa` matches the alternation group, and `sdfsdfsdfsd` consists from alpha or dash.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well the route makes it a valid request but `sdfsdfsdfsd` isn't a page so I need it to throw a `404`. My problem is that no matter what I throw in the second part of the URI it will always be valid and load the latest entry in the channel, even though it doesn't exist

Comment: Maybe because of the empty alternative? Try `{static_country:regex[(zh|cn|usa)]}` (I removed `|` before the last `)`)

Comment: Weird, I had to add that in yesterday for it to work. But it seems to work without it. Editing my question now